# onNodeContextMenuSelect is not working in p-tree

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

```html
<p-tree
  [value]="files"
  selectionMode="single"
  (onNodeContextMenuSelect)="showContect($event)"
>
</p-tree>
```

When I am right clicking, this event is not working. Instead, I am getting default context option of browser.

It should invoke the `showContect` function.

Comment: Could you please share stackblitz code URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Context Menu instance to your html in order to override default context option of browser.
Then you can manage events with Context Menu by `command` defined in `items` or you are able to use `onNodeContextMenuSelect`
Example usage is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mzpwky)

`.html` file

```html
<p-tree
  [value]="files"
  selectionMode="single"
  [contextMenu]="cm"
  (onNodeContextMenuSelect)=showContect($event)
>
</p-tree>

<p-contextMenu
  #cm
  [model]="items"
>
</p-contextMenu>
```

`.ts` file

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.items = [
    {
      label: 'View',
      icon: 'pi pi-search',
      command: (event) => this.viewFile(this.selectedFile),
    },
    {
      label: 'Unselect',
      icon: 'pi pi-times',
      command: (event) => this.unselectFile(),
    },
  ];
}

showContect(event: any) {
  console.log(event.node);
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can prevent opening of context menu if the node type is folder, beside making items to an empty array.

Comment: I have updated the example project according to your last question. I added `type` for data, and made some minor changes in `.ts` and `.html` files to handle your request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onNodeContextMenuSelect` you should use add a `contextmenu` to the `p-tree` component

```html
 <p-tree
  [value]="files"
  selectionMode="single"
  (contexmenu)="showContect($event)"
>
</p-tree>
```

```
showContect(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 console.log('called!')
}
```

Comment: contextmenu is not an emitter. Correct usage can be found in my answer.